# Electrical work sign convention

Tags: physics, electrostatic

[image]
If I understood the correct sign convention it's as shown in the below sketch

[image]

Comment: Ask this question at https://physics.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sketch is right.

Positive charges do repel each other. So moving two positive charges closely together needs some positive work to overcome the repelling force.

A positive and a negative charge do attract each other. So moving them closely together you need negative work (gain of energy).